# how to add argument in test-binary for Watchdog daemon for Linux

Tags: linux, watchdog

for Watchdog daemon for Linux, in watchdog.conf
how to configure a binary with argument, for example,

below it is working

test-binary = /home/test/my_test_binary

below it doesn't work

test-binary = /home/test/my_test_binary -v

even try below, it doesn't work either

test-binary = "/home/test/my_test_binary -v"